# Streetview Publish API with PHP - The upload reference cannot be found

Tags: php, php-curl, google-streetview-publish

I'm having some issues with the Streetview Publish API through PHP, attempting to replicate the procedure listed under "Uploading a photo" in the documentation

https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app

I've got the first part working and can retrieve the upload URL to a variable $upload_url.

This is my code for step 2

```
    $another = array(
        'upload-file' => curl_file_create($imagepath)
    );
    $header = array (
        "Authorization: Bearer $accesstoken",
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
    );
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $upload_url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $another,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);


echo(curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

`curl_error` is not returning anything, and `$response` returns true, so I am assuming the file was properly uploaded.

For step 3, I'm using

```
$data['uploadReference']['uploadUrl']=$upload_url;
$data['pose']['latLngPair']['latitude']=$latitude;
$data['pose']['latLngPair']['longitude']=$longitude;

$data['captureTime']['seconds']=$timestamp;    


$data_string = json_encode($data); 

print_r($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo?key='.$apikey);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                     
  'authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken,
  'Content-Type: application/json',                                             
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                     
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

If I `var_dump($result)`  I get a 404 suggesting that the uploaded file isn't at the `uploadUrl`

```
Array ( [uploadReference] => Array ( [uploadUrl] => https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/XXXX/photo/YYYY ) [pose] => Array ( [latLngPair] => Array ( [latitude] => 53.59398125 [longitude] => -1.95349941 ) ) [captureTime] => Array ( [seconds] => 1502560132 ) ) string(255) 
"{ 
  "error": { 
  "code": 404, 
  "message": "The upload reference cannot be found. Please make sure you have uploaded a file to the upload reference URL. If this error persists, request a new upload URL and try again.", 
  "status": "NOT_FOUND" 
  } 
} "
```

Any advice would be welcome, my instinct is that the issue is with the second step rather than the third, but I'm open to all suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error when I tried uploading panorama pictures.

```
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "The upload reference cannot be found. Please make sure you have uploaded a file to the upload reference URL. If this error persists, request a new upload URL and try again.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
        "detail": "[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::not_found: com.google.geo.ugc.streetview.publish.boq.service.util.ApiException: The upload reference cannot be found. Please make sure you have uploaded a file to the upload reference URL. If this error persists, request a new upload URL and try again. Code: NOT_FOUND [google.rpc.error_details_ext] { message: \"The upload reference cannot be found. Please make sure you have uploaded a file to the upload reference URL. If this error persists, request a new upload URL and try again.\" }"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems that you are not uploading a correct 360 photo. Make sure that the 360 picture you are uploading has [metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata). You may download this [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to check the image.

Comment: Thanks for that, the image files are compatible and have been accepted by uploading through the Streetview Android app (eventually - it's a really awful workflow which is why I'm trying to improve it).

The issue is definitely that the step 2 upload is failing, if I look at curl_getinfo() it's returning a 500 Internal Server Error, but nothing more helpful than that.

Comment: Yes. I've also tried uploading a panorama picture in Streetview which is directly captured by the Streetview app. When I tried uploading the picture using curl, I received the error above. This is because the picture to be published does not have the metadata needed as described in [Photo Sphere XMP Metadata](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata). Here's the sample metadata extracted using the ExifTool: http://imgur.com/L6MC8yd

Comment: I've bodged my script to output a batch file to do the step 2 curl operation before going back to do step 3 via the php script, which works. On that basis I would respectfully disagree that the issue is with the jpg files and their metadata. I am able to manually upload via through the API.  The issue is clearly with parameters for the curl operation through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem in PHP with curl lib at step 2.
Replacing curl-php with a server side call resolved for me but you need to know full file path i.e.:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$webdir.$filename
```

here is my step 2:

```
$result = exec('curl --request POST \--url "'. addslashes($upload_url) .'" \--upload-file "'.$file_name_with_full_path.'" \--header "Authorization: Bearer '. addslashes($_GOOGLE_API['access_token']) .'" ');
```

The server is some sort of cloud hosted Linux system.. hope this helps.