# Upload succes to get the photoId but can not get the uploaded image from this photoId

Tags: curl, google-streetview-publish

I follow the instruction to upload a photo [link](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app).
I get the **photoId** after [call](https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo).
But I can not get the image by call :

```
curl --request GET \
    --url 'streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?key=YOUR_API_KEY' \
    --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

or call:

```
curl --request GET \
    --url 'streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo/PHOTO_ID?key=YOUR_API_KEY' \
    --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

I see the tutorial say that if you get the **photoId** means the upload is the success. How can I make sure my photo is upload success?

update:
    Base on Mr.Rebot's opinion, I add --verbose to see the response detail. But I can not found any error from response. I guess the root cause may be happen on Upload the photo bytes to the Upload URL. I check the response detail. It not show the message like **"* upload completely sent off: 632 out of 632 bytes"** in Upload the metadata of the photo response. But I don't know how to solve it.

the Upload the photo bytes to the Upload URL response is show below:

```js
*   Trying 216.58.200.42...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to streetviewpublish.googleapis.com (216.58.200.42) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.googleapis.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> POST /media/user/114009162009986408485/photo/3946916238102603576 HTTP/1.1
> Host: streetviewpublish.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlvKBHgR75-11mkyh-7Yy0YHSnY2at7ceBKkmcz6Kmt0axDqRD7iTfqp8_nfBZgQrU25V77WKk3gCBZ6w6ce9TBz26mLusLzZqjX7qUGi306Z_PhkPTSqfXZwte2
> Content-Length: 2684889
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Uq1RvuwmbMZizf-MLlPcB8hJC2NBgpaEMR-K_AomU7nIQ7DTkv94Ekij3_zPNyPK7tTypkYywHualC_EnvzCoM2OuosuckDFF8OtoLT97CecFwnYk4
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2017 06:01:25 GMT
< Server: UploadServer
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host streetviewpublish.googleapis.com left intact
```

the Upload the metadata of the photo response is show below:

```js
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 216.58.200.234...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to streetviewpublish.googleapis.com (216.58.200.234) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.googleapis.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> POST /v1/photo?key=AIzaSyBINbdfV0eqE2fdc_ywJzL-oCa7fs_qNrQ HTTP/1.1
> Host: streetviewpublish.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlvKBHgR75-11mkyh-7Yy0YHSnY2at7ceBKkmcz6Kmt0axDqRD7iTfqp8_nfBZgQrU25V77WKk3gCBZ6w6ce9TBz26mLusLzZqjX7qUGi306Z_PhkPTSqfXZwte2
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 632
> 
* upload completely sent off: 632 out of 632 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Vary: X-Origin
< Vary: Referer
< Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2017 05:47:24 GMT
< Server: ESF
< Cache-Control: private
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{
  "photoId": {
    "id": "CAoSLEFGMVFpcE9Zc0I4U25pWkcwaUFRWk11ZXZ3d3VzVkRaUTFxZlIyWks5VnE2"
  }
}
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host streetviewpublish.googleapis.com left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause problem. I miss some XMP meta on my photo. Google not check and response the error for wrong XMP meta photo. So make sure your photo have correct XMP meta is the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `--verbose` at the end of your request when calling Step 2 of [Uploading a photo](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app#sample-requests) (if you are using curl). Also you can also check the response code, if it is 200 then its ok. Lastly, make sure that you are uploading a proper 360 image. Follow this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674293/streetview-publish-api-with-php-the-upload-reference-cannot-be-found#comment78437371_45689952), that talks about photosphere metadata and exiftool

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I can not get the uploaded image if my image not add proper XMP?? The response I update on my topic and is show 200 ok. But I not add XMP on metadata following the https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata. I'll try to add proper XMP and see the result.

Comment: it's weird that after I check my photo. The XMP information is correct following the XMP guide (https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata). I use Nikon theta-s to shoot the panorama. It's XMP is follow the guide. I don't know why I can not use api to get my uploaded image info.